# Copy Password Protected Folders with C#/WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I just need a code section for my program and I have to copy password protected folders. I have to copy this data in the network, so each folder is protected with the username and password of windows. It would be best if the program recognizes that it is password protected, that a new user form is opened where you can enter password and username.

I´m not the best in programming but I tried my best and I can´t figure it out how this could work.

Comment: To get started you can have a look at the Directory.GetAccessControl method.

Comment: I will try and look at it...  thanks

Comment: There are no "password protected" folders on Windows. There are folders with permissions that restrict what *users* can do with their contents and encrypted folders, that ensure the contents can only be read by the user that encrypted them. Both are transparent to users with the appropriate permissions

Comment: Ask whoever manages those folders to give Read, List permission to your account. That's the default permission set when adding a user to a shared folder. If your application runs as a service or a scheduled job, the permissions should be given to the account that runs it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Well, network shares have permission by user account if in a domain... but if in a workgroup, the shares are protected only by password.  And network share permissions seem relevant to the question ("I have to copy this data in the network")